# Excel PivotTables with Dynamic field names

Tags: excel, pivot

I need to complete a large number of pivottable formula using criteria/fieldnames that are above/to left of cells.  The base, static formula is as follows:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("BDGT",'Pipeline PVT'!$A$6,"FiscalQuarter","FY16-Q3","AreaName","Western Europe")
```

I want to grab the value field (BDGT in this example) from the formula heading, which will be BDGT.  But when I replace "BDGT" with a cell reference (ie: A4), I get #REF.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Which cell value, is this the name of a field?

Comment: I meant Cell Reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=GETPIVOTDATA(A4 & "",'Pipeline PVT'!$A$6,"FiscalQuarter","FY16-Q3","AreaName","Western Europe")
```

The `& ""` after A4 is the important bit...